# What is the "View.onTouchListener" equivalent in Jetpack Compose? I need the touch coordinates

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

This is what we would currently use in typical Views: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener

Is there an equivalent in Jetpack Compose?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With `1.0.0` you can use the [**`PointerInput`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/input/pointer/package-summary#pointerinput_1) mod

For example you can use [`detectTapGestures`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/gestures/package-summary#detecttapgestures):

```
Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
    detectTapGestures(
        onPress = {/* Called when the gesture starts */ },
        onDoubleTap = { /* Called on Double Tap */ },
        onLongPress = { /* Called on Long Press */ },
        onTap = { /* Called on Tap */ }
    )
}
```

or the [`detectDragGestures`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/gestures/package-summary#detectdraggestures):

```
Box(
    Modifier
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                change.consumeAllChanges()
                //...
            }
        }
)
```

You can also use some modifiers like: `.scrollable`, `.clickable`, `.draggable`, `.swipeable`.

Answer (score 4):

In compose beta-05 version, you can use:

```
Text("Your Composable", modifier = Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
    detectTransformGestures { centroid, pan, zoom, rotation ->
    }
    // or
    detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->  }
    // or
    detectTapGestures(
        onPress = { offset ->  },
        onDoubleTap = { offset -> },
        onLongPress = { offset -> },
        onTap = { offset ->  }
    )
    // or other similar...
})
```

Comment: I think this was deprecated

Answer (score -1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66807594/413127 is the correct answer.

In addition. to detect tap & drag at the same time, you need to use two `pointerInput` modifiers.

```
modifier
.pointerInput(Unit) {
    detectTapGestures { offset ->
        // on tap    
    }
}
.pointerInput(Unit) {
    detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
        // on drag
    }
}
```