# JetPack compose BottomSheet detects STATE_DRAGGING

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

I need to know when the BottomSheet is collapsed by dragging or programmatically, with [BottomSheetCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback), I can check if the state is BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING. I cannot seem to find the equivalent in Compose [BottomSheetState](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/BottomSheetState), or it is achievable by a different approach?

```
BottomSheetCallback() {
    override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
        when(newState) {
            BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING-> {
                Log.d(TAG, "STATE_DRAGGING")
            }
        }
    }
    override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {
    }
}
```

**Update**:
This solution seems to work for me, https://stackoverflow.com/a/66807594/691626. The bottom sheet can be considered dragged as soon as pressed.